# Best Bluetooth module for the Lilypad?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

So I'm trying to work on a project and need to include bluetooth. The latest problem I have is I'm using a Lilypad Arduino and need to keep the project in the same round area. I was looking at this: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12580 however I'm not sure how I would make it smaller? Does it have to clip on or can I simply solder it in a way that it's resting directly above/below the Lilypad?

Comment: you need to electorally connect the pins, how that's arranged is up to you.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks so basically if I simply just solder it with wires or something and hold it in a casing it'll be fine?

Comment: yes, provided static/water/smooth protection...

Comment: @dandavis Well it's not gonna be exposed to any water or such. Just a very basic case to attach to a person. Thank you though :)